# How can you deduce the size of an array in a function template?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers, struct

I have a bunch of structs like:

```
struct A { ... }
struct B { ... }
struct C { ... }
```

I want to devise a function that can accept arrays of these structs and iterate through each element of the array and call another function like:

```
template <typename T>
ostream& process(ostream& os, const T* array) {
   // output each element of array to os (but how do we know the length?)
}

A a_array[10];
// in practice, this is actually operator<<, so I cannot pass in the
// size explicitly
process(..., a_array);
```

Update: I cannot use any of the std containers here.  It has to be an array unfortunately!

Comment: Why are you not using `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Array-to-pointer decay is *really, really* bad.

Fortunately, C++ has array references, which know their size.

```
template<typename T, size_t N> ostream& process(ostream& os, const T (&arr)[N]) {
    // use N
}
```

Comment: I've always seen `const T (&arr)[N]`, but I suppose it works the same.

Comment: I've no idea, it's been a really long time since I used that syntax.

Comment: I think it is advantageous to drop the const. The template will automatically make the type const if it needs to be, but if you pass in a non-const array I seem to recall it won't know how to handle it.

Comment: The notation const T(&arr)[Size] definitely works to deduce the size of a statically sized array. Leaving off the const has the advantage that the constness is correctly deduced, e.g. when getting an end iterator for the array.

Comment: You guys in this answer are amazing!  Well done!  This perfectly addressed my question!

Comment: @Cash it is perfectly fine to have it "const". That way it also accepts rvalue arrays, like (c++11) `cout << alias<A[]>{a, b, c}`.

Comment: @Dietmar: Oh noes! Code bloat! My binary, it might consume a couple more KB, compared to my hundreds of MB of art and such.

Comment: @DeadMG: There are places where code bloat is an issue. As it happens, I'm working at company where some 32 bit executables frequently failed to compile because the size of the code and data segments (i.e. the statically initialized data) exceeded 2GB. The problem was "fixed" by making the operating system vendor remove the 2GB limit. Most of this stuff isn't due to template instantiations but for some code size matters.

Comment: `size_t` is better than `int` for size arguments.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a `std::vector<T>` instead of an simple array.

```
template <typename T>
ostream& process(ostream& os, const std::vector<T> &array) {
   for(std::vector<T>::const_iterator iterator = array.begin(); iterator != array.end(); ++iterator)
   {
      //...
   }
}
```

Or you can go the std::array way (If your compiler support it and N is constant).

```
template <typename T, int N>
ostream& process(ostream& os, const std::array<T, N> &array) {
   for(std::array<T, N>::const_iterator iterator = array.begin(); iterator != array.end(); ++iterator)
   {
      //...
   }
}

// Usage:
array<int, 10> test;
process(..., test);
```

Comment: why not `std::array<T, N>`? The size is known and constant.

Comment: If the compiler doesn't have `std::array`, `boost::array` is always an option

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following format for arrays:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void foo(const T (&arr)[N]) {
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, size information will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Or, a simple template bounds checked array.

```
template< typename T, unsigned int Size >
class Array
{
    public:

    T& operator[]( unsigned int index )
    {
       assert( index < Size );
       return mElements[ index ];
    }

    const T& operator[]( unsigned int index ) const
    {
       assert( index < Size );
       return mElements[ index ];
    }

    unsigned int Capacity() const
    {
        return Size;
    }

    private:
        T mElements[ Size ];
};
```

And then

```
template< typename T, unsigned int Size >
void Process( Array< T, Size >& array )
{
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < Size; ++i )
    {
        //use array[i]
    }
}
```

And to tie it together

```
Array< int, 10 > array;
Process( array );
```

It's a bit of a roll your own solution, but it's probably roughly equivalent (although a less functional array class) to std::Array or boost